# Calculate hours between two datetime-local inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to get the difference in hours between two datetime-local inputs (start and end date). I'm trying to do it with momentjs library without success. I know that the problem is in the format of the datetime-local inputs, but, there's any way to format it to allow Momentjs to get it and compare? Or should I try with a different library/input?

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="input-time" id="start-time">
<input id="end-time" type="datetime-local" onchange="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">              

function myFunction() {
  var initialTime=document.getElementById("start-time");
  var initialTimeFormat=moment(initialTime);
  var endTime=document.getElementById("end-time");
  var endTimeFormat=moment(endTime);
  var totalHours=endTimeFormat.diff(initialTimeFormat,"hours");
  $("#total-hours").text(totalHours); 
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always like a vanilla option and since you only use hours we can go without a library such as moment. However it's a good library to use for comparing dates and more.

As said in other answers the real problem lays in the retrieval of the values:

```
$("input#start-time").val()); //retrieving using jQuery.

document.getElementById("start-time").value; //retrieving using vanilla. | old
document.querySelector("#start-time").value; //retrieving using vanilla. | modern
```

Also the use of inline events is inadvisable. Use `addEventListener`.

```js
 document.querySelector("#end-time").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  function split(time)
  {
    var t = time.split(":");
    return parseInt((t[0] * 60), 10) + parseInt(t[1], 10); //convert to minutes and add minutes
    
  }

  //value start
  var start = split($("input#start-time").val()); //format HH:MM
  
  //value end
  var end = split($("input#end-time").val()); //format HH:MM

  totalHours = NaN;
  if (start < end)
  {
    totalHours = Math.floor((end-start)/60);
  }
  
  $("#total-hours").val(totalHours); 
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input-time" id="start-time" placeholder="HH:MM">
<input id="end-time" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM" >
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">
```

With date-selector (Chrome, Firefox and Edge). Here we use timestamp to compare. Get both timestamps with `Date.parse`. Since an input with `datetime-local` will always give us a correctly formatted ISO-date. Subtracting the timestamps gives us the difference in milliseconds. Some basic divisions leaves us with the amount of hours.

```js
document.querySelector("#end-time").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

  //value start
  var start = Date.parse($("input#start-time").val()); //get timestamp

  //value end
  var end = Date.parse($("input#end-time").val()); //get timestamp

  totalHours = NaN;
  if (start < end) {
    totalHours = Math.floor((end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60); //milliseconds: /1000 / 60 / 60
  }

  $("#total-hours").val(totalHours);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local" name="input-time" id="start-time" placeholder="HH:MM">
<input id="end-time" type="datetime-local" placeholder="HH:MM">
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the simple vanilla solution :).
Very useful!

Answer (score 3):

Your first issue is:

```
var initialTimeFormat=moment(initialTime);
```

You need to pass a value not an element to moment: change initialTime to initialTime.value

Your second issue is:

```
$("#total-hours").text(totalHours);
```

You need to use val instead of text.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var initialTime=document.getElementById("start-time");
    //
    // test if the start time is not empty
    //
    if (initialTime.value.trim() == '') {
        document.getElementById("start-time").focus();
        return;
    }
    var initialTimeFormat=moment(initialTime.value);
    var endTime=document.getElementById("end-time");
    var endTimeFormat=moment(endTime.value);
    var totalHours=endTimeFormat.diff(initialTimeFormat,"hours");
    $("#total-hours").val(totalHours);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>


<input type="datetime-local" name="input-time" id="start-time">
<input id="end-time" type="datetime-local" onchange="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">
```

Comment: `Warning: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.` When only putting in `HH:MM` format.

Comment: Well Edges fires the change-event (inline events are blocked in chrome) and then moment creates the warning above if you only put in the HH:MM format.

Comment: @Mouser Thanks so much. I'll take a look. Give me time

Comment: However about my warning: this happened on IE11, where `datetime-local` isn't supported and where you have to build a correct datestring yourself.

Comment: @Mouser Snippet updated. Now it works on edge. For IE11 you are right. This element is new and ie11 is no more supported by MS. Let me know if you have other points. In any case Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You got the value from the date input in a wrong way.
I also added some validations.
Check out this working example.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var initialTime = $("#start-time").val();
  if (initialTime == "") {
    alert("Please add Start Time (HH : MM : SS)");
    return;
  }
  var initialTimeFormat = moment(initialTime);


  var endTime = $("#end-time").val();
  if (endTime == "") {
    alert("Please add End Time (HH : MM : SS)");
    return;
  }
  var endTimeFormat = moment(endTime);
  
  var difference = endTimeFormat.diff(initialTimeFormat,"hours"); 
  console.log("Time Difference: ", difference, " hours");  
  $("#total-hours").val(difference);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>

<input type="datetime-local" name="input-time" id="start-time">
<input id="end-time" type="datetime-local">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate Time</button><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this HTML...

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="start-time" id="start-time">
<input type="datetime-local" name="end-time" id="end-time">
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">
```

... you can calculate the difference with this...

```
$("input#end-time").change(function() {
    var startDate = moment($("input#start-time").val());
    var endDate = moment($(this).val());
    $("input#total-hours").val(endDate.diff(startDate,'hours'));
});
```

This triggers the calculation only when you change the end-date (like in your example) and without validation. You should check that the input has content, etc.

I hope it helps

Comment: Startdate uses end-time selector now, should be start-time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your compare two input and not there value. Here's the answer:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="input-time" id="start-time">
<input id="end-time" type="datetime-local" onchange="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="total-hours" placeholder="Total Hours">              

function myFunction() {
    var initialTime = document.getElementById("start-time").value;
    var initialTimeFormat = moment(initialTime);
    var endTime = document.getElementById("end-time").value;
    var endTimeFormat = moment(endTime);
    var totalHours = endTimeFormat.diff(initialTimeFormat,"hours");

    document.getElementById("total-hours").innerHTML = totalHours; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction(){
    startTime = Date.parse(document.querySelector("#start-time").value);
    endTime =  Date.parse(document.querySelector("#end-time").value);
    output = document.querySelector("#total-hours");
    output.value = (((Math.abs( startTime - endTime ) / 1000)/60)/60) + "hs";
}
```

This convert start and end time to milliseconds, calculate the gap and then convert it to hours.